# predifined decimals

Tags: regex

i'm trying to build an expression to check decimals as below:

```
valid number with 6 digits and/or precision of 1-4 digits 
---------
656545
452568.1
574896.001
698547.2558

Not valid numbers:
---------
65456.23 - less than 6 main digits
6542166 - more than 6
652541.23165 - more than 4 digits of precision
```

So far i've made this:

```
\b\d{6}\.?\d{0,4}?
```

but it matches also numbers with more than 6 digits and/or more than 4 digits of precision.
Any help?

Comment: Use anchors and an optional non-capturing group - `^\d{6}(?:\.\d{1,4})?$`

Comment: What do you mean by [*the number is within a line*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309443/predifined-decimals#comment87635539_50309505)? Please provide a real life input and expected output.

Comment: Why `?`. It makes the previous piece optional. The decimal dot must not be optional (or, if optional, it should not be present when there are no digits after it) the digits after the dot are already optional because of `{0,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I think I understand you, from a *numerical perspective*, something like this:

No pad: `(?<![\d.])[1-9]\d{5}(?:\.\d{0,3}[1-9])?(?![\d.])`

Demo:  https://regex101.com/r/68gLUF/1

Zero's padded: `(?<![\d.])0*[1-9]\d{5}(?:\.\d{0,3}[1-9]0*)?(?![\d.])`

Readable version:

```
 (?<! [\d.] )         # Digit boundary
 [1-9] \d{5}          # Required, Valid 6 digit whole number 100,000 - 999,999
 (?:                  # Optional, Valid decimal fraction .0001 - .9999
      \.
      \d{0,3} 
      [1-9] 
 )?
 (?! [\d.] )          # Digit boundary
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you make my day. was searching 3 days for the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
\b\d{6}\.?\d{0,4}?
```

The issue here is that the decimal point is optional.  This allows for matching a 10 digit number (first six digits, and then 0 to 4 more)... and possibly even more afterwards as there is no anchoring after `\d{0,4}?`.

Instead:

```
\b\d{6}(\.\d{1,4})?(?!\.)\b
```

This way, the decimal point is not optional *if there are decimals in the number*.  The `(?!\.)` (a negative look-ahead pattern) at the end ensures that the number is not followed by a dot.

If the number occurs on a line by itself (or alone in a string or record, or whatever you have):

```
^\d{6}(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

Comment: thanks, but this matches also a number with anything main digits and 6 digits of precision

Comment: If the number ends in a newline, I would suggest rather using `$` (string end) than the negative lookahead.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Yes, but since he already used `\b` at the start of the pattern in the question, I kinda assumed that this may be a number somewhere within a line, not on a line of its own.  If the number is alone on the line, than they should definitely use `^` at the start and `$` at the end. I added a note about this.

Comment: the number is within a line